# custom controls, dynamic creation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I've created a custom control in asp.net, if I drag it onto another web page it works fine, as expected, however I want to use it dynamically as in

```
   Dim lCustomControl as new cldButton
```

However I can't work out how to do this, the compiler does not recoginise the cldButton as a control.I will add it to the page latter in the code. I've added the following to the web.config.

```
<controls>
        <add tagPrefix="cldButton" tagName="cldButton" src ="~/UserControls/customControlButton.ascx"/>
```

But it seems to make as much differance as my typing is making

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Page.LoadControl method instead of doing a new to create the custom control.  Here's the C# syntax (sorry, I'm not a vb.net guy); it should be easy to convert:

```
Control customControl = Page.LoadControl("mycustomercontrol.ascx");
customControl.ID = "someID";
ICustomControl customControlType = (ICustomControl) customControl;
```

I use Web Sites so I have to create an interface for the custom control and manage it that way.  If you use web applications, you can cast the customControl right to the type of your control.

And, after you have everything setup, you need to add the control to it's container (I typically use a PlaceHolder control).

Comment: Superb, was using the LoadControl (see bellow) , but didn't think to cast to an interface ... damn you vb.net. Cheers for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you're talking about creating a control using just code (and not markup), you don't need to add anything to the web.config file.

Simply instantiate a new instance of your control, and add it to the page's Controls collection during Page_Init.

```
Dim myControl As new cldButton

Page.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

Comment: Sorry didn't make my question exactly clear, that is what I am doing, however the IDE isn't recognising the Dim as new cldButton (I then intend to add it to the Cell, to a TableRow and then the the Table already on the Page) can't understand why

Comment: I hear what you are saying about not adding it to the web.config, however I added this on advice when the original code (exacly like yours) refused to compile,

Comment: Is your control in a different project or assembly?  Did you add a reference to it?

Comment: No the control is created is the same ASP.NET website

Comment: type 'cldButton' is not defined, and yes that is the correct name. I have found that 

Dim lButton As UserControl = LoadControl("~/UserControls/customControlButton.ascx")

Works and allows to add the control to the page, but not access the custom properties .. sigh

Comment: I didn't realize that you were talking about a custom usercontrol, sorry I was assuming it was a class derived from WebControl.  Jeff's answer is what you want.